# Postgresql Create Unique Index

Tags: postgresql

I want to create unique index on mobile_number_1 and mobile_number_2 columns.

by which mobile_number_1 values not get repeated in mobile_number_1 as well as in mobile_number_2

and mobile_number_2 not get repeated in mobile_number_1 as well as mobile_number_2

my table structure :

```
id | mobile_number_1 | mobile_number_2 | city
```

Comment: why don't you create child table with mobile numbers? It's more relational approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should do it (haven't tested it thoroughly though)

```
create unique index idx_unique_mobile_number1
 on person (least(mobile_number_1, mobile_number_2));

create unique index idx_unique_mobile_number2
 on person (greatest(mobile_number_1, mobile_number_2));
```

Comment: Another possibility could have been `alter table person add phone_excl exclude using gist ((array[phone1, phone2]) with &&);` if there had been the needed operator class.

Comment: @Denis: nice idea. I always forget about the exclusion constraints. You should add that as an answer

Comment: Nah, I like yours better. The exclude requires to additionally create an operator class for varchar arrays. :-P

Answer (score -3):

That is practically impossible, you have to do in your code, add a trigger, or rule.
Indices are for only one column or several columns altogether.

Comment: This is incorrect: it actually *is* possible. It should probably have been a comment, too, or expanded so it is a bit more verbose.

Comment: yeah I guess, thanks, above answer made me learn something new